# How to write a GraphQL query that will use a range filter on an integer field using `django-filters`?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python, django-filters

I am using `graphene-python`, `django-filters` and `relay` in my GraphQL API. Let's imagine I have a type `FrameType` which has an integer field `time_offset` and I would like to be able to use a **range** on it - ask only for frames which have the `time_offset` within the given range. I prepared my `schema.py` according to the [graphene-python docs](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/filtering/#custom-filtersets) with a custom `FilterSet`:

```py
import django_filters
from graphene import ObjectType, relay
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType, filter
from my_app.blabla import models



class FrameFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    time_offset = django_filters.RangeFilter()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Frame
        fields = ("time_offset",)


class FrameType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Frame
        filterset_class = FrameFilter
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)


class Query(ObjectType):
    frames = filter.DjangoFilterConnectionField(FrameType)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

However, I have no idea how to query the `timeOffset` field now. I found no examples online for the `django_filters.RangeFilter` field. This is a query I tried:

```
query Frame {
  frames(first: 20, timeOffset: "{\"gt\":\"4350\", \"lt\":\"5000\"}") {
    edges {
      node {
        timeOffset
    }
  }
}
```

... also with these alternatives:

```
timeOffset: "{\"gt\":4350, \"lt\":5000}"
timeOffset: "{\"start\":\"4350\", \"end\":\"5000\"}"
timeOffset: "{\"min\":\"4350\", \"max\": \"4500\"}"
timeOffset: "[\"4350\", \"5000\"]"
timeOffset: "[4350, 5000]"
timeOffset: "[4350]"
timeOffset: "4350,5000"
```

These queries don't raise any error, but they don't filter either (all results are returned). I am lost, I'm not sure if I still haven't found the proper syntax, or maybe there's some mistake in my backend code. How should I use and query the `django_filters.RangeFilter` on a field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, this isn't possible. But, there is a workaround for it

Adjust your filter class as

```
def custom_range_filter_method(queryset, field_name, value):
    if value:
        queryset = queryset.filter(**{f'{field_name}__range': value.split(',')})
    return queryset


class FrameFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    time_offset = filters.Filter(method=custom_range_filter_method)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Frame
        fields = ("time_offset",)
```

Now query the schema with

```
query Frame {
  frames(first: 20, timeOffset: "4350,5000") {
    edges {
      node {
        timeOffset
    }
  }
}
```

#### Reference

- Customize filter result with [**`Filter.method`**--(`django-filter` doc)](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#customize-filtering-with-filter-method)

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the **range** option at Django's queryset level without disturbing the existing relay query.

In your case,

1. Pass `start_time_offset` and `end_time_offset` arguments to `DjangoConnectionField`
2. Override `resolve_frames`
3. filter on django queryset if `start_time_offset` or `end_time_offset` is provided by user else return `objects.all()`

```python
class Query(ObjectType):
    frames = filter.DjangoFilterConnectionField(FrameType, start_time_offset=graphene.Int(), end_time_offset=graphene.Int())

    def resolve_frames(self, info, start_time_offset=None, end_time_offset=None, **kwargs):
        if start_time_offset and end_time_offset:
            return Frame.objects.filter(time_offset__range=(start_time_offset, end_time_offset))
        elif start_time_offset:
            return Frame.objects.filter(time_offset__gte=start_time_offset)
        elif end_time_offset:
            return Frame.objects.filter(time_offset__lte=end_time_offset)
        return Frame.objects.all()
```

Now you can query on it with your regular filters provided by relay:

```graphql
query Frame {
  frames(last: 5, startTimeOffset: 4350, endTimeOffset:5000) {
    edges {
      node {
        timeOffset
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old but since it might help others, you can check this [thread](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/92#issuecomment-275330239), it used django filterset for DateRangeFiled and I think you can use a similar approach for integers using filterset [RangeFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#rangefilter). Also check [this](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/blob/main/docs/filtering.rst#custom-filtersets) for more info about filterset in graphene.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is update your FrameType class as follows:

```
class FrameType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Frame
        filterset_fields = {
            'time_offset': ['range']
        }
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
```

You do not need a custom filterset for this.
Then you can query as follows:

```
query Frame {
    frames(first: 20, timeOffset_Range: ["4350", "5000"]) {
    edges {
      node {
        timeOffset
    }
  }
}
```